# aws cloud formation nested stack exporting/ Importing values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

i'm creating a cloud formation nested templates for automate aws infrastructure. Basically i have parent configuration as following

```
"Resources": {
    "VPCStack": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
                    "ClassB": {                      

                           "Ref": "ClassB"                     

                    }                
                },
          "TemplateURL": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/vpc.json",
          "TimeoutInMinutes": "5"
      }
    },
    "NatStack": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
                    "ParentVPCStack": { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
                    "SubnetZone": {"Ref": "SubnetZone"}           
                },
          "TemplateURL": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/nat-gateway.json",
          "TimeoutInMinutes": "5"
      },
      "DependsOn": "VPCStack"
    }
  }
```

above will trigger nested CF and i have export outputs in VPC as following

```
"Outputs": {
                "StackName": {
            "Description": "Stack name.",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}"
            }
        },
        "AZs": {
            "Description": "AZs",
            "Value": 2,
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-AZs"
                }
            }
        },
        "AZA": {
            "Description": "AZ of A",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Select": [
                    0,
                    {
                        "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-AZA"
                }
            }
        },
        "AZB": {
            "Description": "AZ of B",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Select": [
                    1,
                    {
                        "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-AZB"
                }
            }
        },
        "ClassB": {
            "Description": "Class B.",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "ClassB"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-ClassB"
                }
            }
        },
        "VPC": {
            "Description": "VPC.",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "VPC"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-VPC"
                }
            }
        },
        "SubnetsPublic": {
            "Description": "Subnets public.",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    ",",
                    [
                        {
                            "Ref": "SubnetAPublic"
                        },
                        {
                            "Ref": "SubnetBPublic"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetsPublic"
                }
            }
        },
        "SubnetsPrivate": {
            "Description": "Subnets private.",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    ",",
                    [
                        {
                            "Ref": "SubnetAPrivate"
                        },
                        {
                            "Ref": "SubnetBPrivate"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetsPrivate"
                }
            }
        },
        "RouteTablePrivate": {
            "Description": "Route table private (deprecated in v4, will be removed in v5).",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "RouteTablePrivate"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-RouteTablePrivate"
                }
            }
        }
```

then i have nat gateway also VPC creates without a problem but when creating nat gateway i get this error
No export named ${stack-name}-RouteTableAPrivate found

i have these outputs in my main CF

```
"Outputs": {

   "StackRef": {"Value": { "Ref" : "VPCStack"}},

     "Output1FromNestedmyVPCStack" : {

          "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "VPCStack", "Outputs.RouteTableAPrivate" ] }

      }

   }
}
```

how can i resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Your exported value is does not have an A between RouteTable and Private, where as your referenced value does (RouteTableAPrivate)

Comment: here. "RouteTableAPrivate": {
            "Description": "Route table A private.",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "RouteTablePrivate"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-RouteTableAPrivate"
                }
            }

Comment: and i export from this and import from nat gateway cf

Comment: "Route": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${ParentVPCStack}-RouteTable${SubnetZone}Private"
                    }
                }

Comment: json templates are hard enough to read so don't paste more json here, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you have "**${AWS::StackName}**-RouteTablePrivate" in your nested stack.

Nested Stacks get generated names that you won't know about in advance.

So, simply name it your resource "**RouteTablePrivate**". That should be all based on my hypothesis.